# Out-of-sample forecast h>2; using rolling window scheme in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to perform an rolling window forecast scheme using some mthly FRED data. I want to apply univariate models such as AR1, AR2, random walk and ARIMA to predict the future unemployment rate in the upcoming 12 month (horizon).

```
library(forecast)

# Sample data
x <- data$UNRATE[700:765]

# Rolling window of 24
forecast24_arima1 <- rep(NA,length(x))
forecast24_arima2 <- rep(NA,length(x))
forecast24_rw <- rep(NA,length(x))
forecast24_arima_auto <- rep(NA,length(x))

for (i in 25:length(x)) {
  x_train <- x[(i-24):(i-1)]
  fit1 <- Arima(x_train, order = c(1,0,0))
  fit2 <- Arima(x_train, order = c(2,0,0))
  fit3 <- meanf(x_train, h=1)
  fit4 <- auto.arima(x_train)
  forecast24_arima1[i] <- predict(fit1, n.ahead = 1)$pred[1]
  forecast24_arima2[i] <- predict(fit2, n.ahead = 1)$pred[1]
  forecast24_rw[i] <- predict(fit3, n.ahead = 1)$pred[1]
  forecast24_arima_auto[i] <- predict(fit4, n.ahead = 1)$pred[1]
}

# Rolling window of 60
forecast60_arima1 <- rep(NA,length(x))
forecast60_arima2 <- rep(NA,length(x))
forecast60_rw <- rep(NA,length(x))
forecast60_arima_auto <- rep(NA,length(x))

for (i in 61:length(x)) {
  x_train <- x[(i-60):(i-1)]
  fit1 <- Arima(x_train, order = c(1,0,0))
  fit2 <- Arima(x_train, order = c(2,0,0))
  fit3 <- meanf(x_train, h=1)
  fit4 <- auto.arima(x_train)
  forecast60_arima1[i] <- predict(fit1, n.ahead = 1)$pred[1]
  forecast60_arima2[i] <- predict(fit2, n.ahead = 1)$pred[1]
  forecast60_rw[i] <- predict(fit3, n.ahead = 1)$pred[1]
  forecast60_arima_auto[i] <- predict(fit4, n.ahead = 1)$pred[1]
}

# Print forecasts
print(forecast24_arima1)
print(forecast24_arima2)
print(forecast24_rw)
print(forecast24_arima_auto)
```

These are some of the latest values of unemployment rate:

```
c(4.1, 4, 4, 3.8, 4, 3.8, 
3.8, 3.7, 3.8, 3.8, 3.9, 4, 3.8, 3.8, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.7, 3.7, 
3.5, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.5, 3.5, 4.4, 14.7, 13.2, 11, 10.2, 8.4, 
7.9, 6.9, 6.7, 6.7, 6.4, 6.2, 6, 6, 5.8, 5.9, 5.4, 5.2, 4.7, 
4.6, 4.2, 3.9, 4, 3.8, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.5, 3.7, 3.5)
```

I tried several r packages, such as zoo, OOS or greybox, but they do not seem to work adequatly.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and show the code you have tried so far? Also perhaps include a bit more information about what exactly you are trying to do. At the moment your question does not contain enough information to allow us to answer.

Comment: I have added the code I have build and the latest available unemployment rates in the US. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Econ. Is that monthly data?

Comment: Yes it is monthly data.

Answer (score 0):

I used the greybox package, see the code below.

```
z <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
# ci defines constant in-sample window size, co defines whether the holdout sample window size should be constant
ourCall <- "predict(arima(x=data,order=c(1,0,0)),n.ahead=h)"
# Ask for predicted values and the standard error
ourValue <- c("pred","se")
# Return a list for an forecasting horizon h with a rolling holdout size equal to origin
ValuesAR1 <- ro(z, h=2, origins=3, call=ourCall, value=ourValue, ci=TRUE, co=TRUE)
# calculate MAE
MAE_AR1 <- apply(abs(ValuesAR1$holdout - ValuesAR1$pred),1,mean,na.rm=TRUE) / mean(ValuesAR1$actuals)
MAE_AR1 <- as.matrix(MAE_AR1)
MAE_AR1
ValuesAR1[[3]]
```

For further reading see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/greybox/vignettes/ro.html